# Problem with comparing Merge and Insertion Sort

Tags: python, algorithm

Im trying to run insertion sort and merge sort and plot them. Im taking the time for 5 different N and plot them. I want to do this three times such that Insertion time < merge time,  Insertion time = merge time and Insertion time > merge time. However, No matter what I set as N, Insertion sort is always much faster. This is my output for N = 5000

N Values:  [1, 1001, 2001, 3001, 4001]

Merge Sort:  [0.005, 11.198, 21.965, 35.996, 49.971000000000004]

Insertion Sort:  [0.002, 0.268, 0.545, 0.9129999999999999, 1.177]

I have tried different N up to like 10000000 and merge sort is always slower. What am I missing here?

```
def insertion_sort(array):
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    for j in range(1, len(array)):
        key = array[j]
        i = j - 1
        while i >= 0 and array[i] > key:
            array[i + 1] = array[i]
            i -= 1
        array[i + 1] = key
    time_diff = datetime.datetime.now() - start_time
    return time_diff.total_seconds() * 1000

def merge_sort(arr, p, r):
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    if p < r:
        m = (p + (r - 1)) // 2
        merge_sort(arr, p, m)
        merge_sort(arr, m + 1, r)
        merge(arr, p, m, r)

    time_diff = datetime.datetime.now() - start_time
    return time_diff.total_seconds() * 1000

def merge(arr, p, q, r):
    n1 = q - p + 1
    n2 = r - q

    L = [0] * (n1 + 1)
    R = [0] * (n2 + 1)

    for i in range(0, n1):
        L[i] = arr[p + i]

    for j in range(0, n2):
        R[j] = arr[q + 1 + j]

    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = p

    while i < n1 and j < n2:
        if L[i] <= R[j]:
            arr[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            arr[k] = R[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1

    while i < n1:
        arr[k] = L[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1

    while j < n2:
        arr[k] = R[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1
    return arr

x, y1, y2 = [], [], []
N = 5000
for i in range(1, N, N // 5):
    array = [j for j in range(i)]
    array = array[::-1] # Array in reversed order
    x.append(i)
    y1.append(merge_sort(array, 0, len(array) - 1))
    y2.append(insertion_sort(array))
```

[image: My plot, obviously not correct.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

Your test is not correct, as you don't provide the same array order to the two sorting algorithms.

As the first algorithm sorts the array (in-place), the second gets a sorted array.

To make a fair comparison, make sure to make a copy of the *original* array, e.g. using `[:]`:

```
y1.append(merge_sort(array[:], 0, len(array) - 1))
y2.append(insertion_sort(array[:]))
```

And now the results will show what you really expected.

Comment: Additionally, it's worth noting that the array that gets handed to merge sort is generated in reverse order.  If OP wants worst-case behavior for insertion sort, your fix is all that's needed, but if they want "typical" behavior randomization seems in order.

Comment: Wow I feel like such a noob.. Can't believe I just did that mistake..

Answer (score 2):

Insertion sort runs *very* fast on sorted arrays. It just does n comparisons, and that's it.

So, a question for you: Why is insertion sort called with a sorted array in your code?

Hint: Try changing the order of these two lines and see how the running times change:

```py
    y1.append(merge_sort(array, 0, len(array) - 1))
    y2.append(insertion_sort(array))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing several significant factors:

1. Algorithmic complexity is a ratio as `N` approaches infinity.  You're nowhere near infinity.  :-)  Some algorithms have a high overhead, such that their efficiencies don't begin to dominate execution time until you get to much larger lists.
2. If you want to see these efficiency effects, you have to *efficiently* implement the algorithms.  Your code has a lot of superfluous overhead, especially in the merge sort.  I recommend that you research a better implementation, as you're doing some extra copying and list building that adds nothing to the final result.
3. Whatever you choose to implement, you need to research its properties.  As you can see from the raw figures and the graph, both of your functions are still dependent most on the linear and constant components of the implementation, and have no yet reached the parts of the curve dominated by the **N^2** and **N log N** terms.